# How to find out how many people are using a script that you created?

Tags: jquery, plugins, web-crawler

I created a jQuery plugin and was wondering if anyone knows of a way to track how many people are using it? Is there a way to crawl websites and return a yes if a website is using it?

Comment: First, get employed by Google...

Comment: Put a backdoor in your code which pings your server every time its used

Comment: @Raynos - and hope someone doesn't remove that ping and make it available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could crawl websites, look for key JS includes or parse the existing JS includes and look for your code, but that would be a huge task.  Crawling even a small piece of the web is a big job.  Do you have any idea how many web pages there are on the web?   As of several years ago, Google was examining more than a trillion URLs.

If you were really lucky, you might find some special kind of search that would let you use existing search engines (like Google) to find hits for you, but I don't think they index Javascript so I'm guessing that might not be possible.

If this is really important and something more than just an idle curiosity, then you might have to invent some sort of registration system where people can use your script, but only if they register each site with you.  That would probably only work for some sites and would probably stop some others from the bother, but you'd at least get some idea.